# Update value in a cell based on summation of other cells matching other grouping variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this -

```
  Alpha Title   Jan Feb Mar Apr
0   a   T1      63  66  65  53
1   b   T2      35  88  81  42
2   b   T3       0  23  51  95
3   c   T2      83  70  77  57
4   c   T3       0  81  15  59
```

I want to update the value in column `Jan` where `Title = T3` using summation of values from `Jan, Feb and Mar` where `Title = T2`, with matching `Alpha`

The output should look like this -

```
      Alpha Title   Jan Feb Mar Apr
    0   a   T1      63  66  65  53
    1   b   T2      35  88  81  42
    2   b   T3      204 23  51  95
    3   c   T2      83  70  77  57
    4   c   T3      230 81  15  59
```

Comment: Do you want replace by `0` values or by `T3` rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
#create Series for match by conditions and columns names
df1 = df.set_index('Alpha')
s = df1.loc[df1['Title'].eq('T2'), ['Jan','Feb','Mar']].sum(1)

#another condition
m = df['Title'].eq('T3')
#replace by mask
df.loc[m, 'Jan'] = df.loc[m, 'Alpha'].map(s)
print (df)
  Alpha Title  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr
0     a    T1   63   66   65   53
1     b    T2   35   88   81   42
2     b    T3  204   23   51   95
3     c    T2   83   70   77   57
4     c    T3  230   81   15   59
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stack and cumsum on the first level keeping the *not to be summed* columns as index and using `mask` replace where condition matches:

```
m = df.set_index(['Alpha','Title','Apr'])
m = m.mask(m.eq(0),m.stack().groupby(level=0).cumsum()
     .unstack()).reset_index().reindex(df.columns,axis=1)
```

---

```
print(m) 
  Alpha Title  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr
0     a    T1   63   66   65   53
1     b    T2   35   88   81   42
2     b    T3  204   23   51   95
3     c    T2   83   70   77   57
4     c    T3  230   81   15   59
```

Note: You can generalize this by just keeping the columns which are not to be summed as index